# Enclosing javascript code in comment tags "<!-- //-->"

Tags: javascript, jquery, tags, comments, cdata

Many years ago I developed a habit of enclosing all javascript in files with

```
<!--

code here

//-->
```

Not exactly sure why.. other than it's hiding (or not parsing) the code from old browsers, am I right?

Do I need to use it still?
Do I even need anything in my JS pages other than the script code itself? (I'm using Jquery too)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I thought that this was to cover script embedded in the HTML page itself, not in a separate file...

Comment: If your browser do not support js, it will be commented, else there is no difference

Comment: What happens when that browser with disabled JS sees the page without the comment-tags around?

Comment: @mowgli A browser with JS disabled will process the `<script>` tag's existence just like if JS were enabled. It just won't actually execute the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML comment was intended to hide the JavaScript from ancient browsers that didn't understand the `<script>` element and instead render its contents on the page. HTML comments, ie. `<!-- -->,` are no longer needed. You can read more about this [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#h-18.3.2)